# Test the return value of my function correctly at the time of return

Tags: javascript

I can not test the return value of my function correctly at the time of return.

My exercise is this: I must compare two arrays and return true if they have at least one identical element but I need some assistance in figuring out what is wrong with my code:

```
function duplicateElements(m, n){
  function test (element){
    return n.includes(element);
  }
  return m.filter(test) != [] ? true:false;
}
```

Comment: it deeply hurts :)

Comment: s/he needs to compare two arrays and return true if it has at least one identical element.

Comment: Tu dois testes la propriété `length` de la valeur de retour -> `m.filter(test).length > 0`

Comment: Ah super! Je te remercie !

Comment: try this - https://jsfiddle.net/79ynncue/

Comment: Thank you @marmeladze :)

Comment: il n'y a pas de quoi -))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not in English.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to test the `length` property of the return value.

```
function duplicateElements(m, n) {
    function test(element) {
        return n.includes(element);
    }

    return m.filter(test).length > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: It is nicer to remove `? true : false`. It the `>` operator already returns a boolean.