# Convert String to Date in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I retrieve a date variable from a JSON object in a string format, but I am having trouble getting the elapsed time until now.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Date extends React.Component {
render() {

    console.log(this.props.date); //shows: 2017-01-25T10:18:18Z

    var date = Date.parse(this.props.date.toString());

    console.log(date.getTime());

    return (
        <div >
      </div>
    );
   }
}
```

Comment: I think somebody voted it down because it was in French.  I don't know if there is a French language version of the site but this particular version is English-only.

Comment: Désolé, nous acceptons uniquement les questions en langue anglaise. Apparemment, personne n'a jugé nécessaire de vous informer de cela quand vous avez posé [votre première question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40946427/tester-la-valeur-de-retour-dune-fonction-au-moment-du-return). Vous voilà donc prévenu(e).

Comment: Oui effectivement! Merci pour la remarque, je saurai pour la prochaine fois

Answer (score 12):

If it is not a date object, just create a new date object.

```
 var date = new Date(this.props.date); 
 var elapsed = date.getTime(); // Elapsed time in MS
```

If it is a date object, just call `this.props.date.getTime()`

Answer (score 0):

```
let timeStamp = Date.parse("14 Oct 2022");
    console.log(timeStamp);

// Create a new JavaScript Date object based on the timestamp

// If require milliseconds then multiplied by 1000 so that the argument is in milliseconds.

var date = new Date(timeStamp);

var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = months[date.getMonth()];
var dateVal = date.getDate();


var formattedDate = dateVal + '/' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + year;
   
console.log(formattedDate); --> 14/10/2022
```